# PixelCompare Extension Configuration

Tags: autodesk-forge

How can we change/manage the text header of the pixel compare panel and also show original names of the documents instead of Document1 and Document2 in PixelCompare extension.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvrQN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which viewer version you're using. Here is a code snippet for 7.3x. You can specify the document names by passing `title` you want for each model to 3rd & 4th function arguments. It can contain `title`, `version`, `creationTime` & `creator`.

```js
pixelCompareExt.compareTwoModels( model1, model2, { title: 'Model1' }, { title: 'Model2' } )
```

Comment: Thanks Eason, that was helpful. However, how do we change the header of the Compared documents Panel titled 'Compared Documents'? Can we also configure it as per the language. Right now, in  German the spellings are wrong and has to be "Dokumente vergleichen". Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Vandana. I've logged a request with the viewer team (LMV-5958).